# Apache server adds .php extension before running the Rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I reinstalled apache2 on my local machine (Mac OS X), and I have this problem:

I had some Rewrite rules working before. I have this rule before anyone else:

```
RewriteRule ^v1/users/authenticate$ /v1/users_authenticate.php [L]
```

I have the file **users.php** in the /v1 folder too. So, if I try to call **http://localhost/v1/users/authenticate**

I see in the Rewrite logs that server tries to match as:

**add path info postfix: /v1/users.php -> /v1/users.php/authenticate**

If I remove the users.php file, rules work normally.

So, by asking users/authenticate and users.php existing, it takes users.php and works with it. If users.php doesn't exist, it runs the rules as expected.

Notice that Rewrite engine works normally in every other case.

- Experiment 1: If I create a v1.php file at root, nothing happens.
- Experiment 2: If I rename the users.php to users.wtf, the same happens, this time adding the .wtf extension before running the rules

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following in your htaccess file:

Options -MultiViews

Comment: Thanks @Krisleo, I removed MultiViews from the httpd.conf Options and works fine. Me feelz ztupid :)